# Sharing data between several Google projects

Tags: backup, google-cloud-storage

A question about Google Storage:

Is it possible to give r/o access to a (not world-accessible) storage bucket to a user from **another** Google project?

If yes, how?

I want it to backup data to **another** Google project, for the case if somebody may incidentally delete all storage buckets from our project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Access to Google Cloud Storage buckets and objects are controlled by ACLs that allow you to specify individual users, service accounts, groups, or project role.

You can add users to any existing object through the UI, the `gsutil` command-line utility, or via any of the APIs.

If you want to grant one specific user the ability to write objects into project X, you need only specify the user's email:

```
$> gsutil acl ch -u bob.smith@gmail.com:W gs://bucket-in-project-x
```

If you want to say that every member of the project my-project is permitted to write into some bucket in a different project, you can do that as well:

```
$> gsutil acl ch -p members-my-project:W gs://bucket-in-project-x
```

The "-u" means user, "-p" means 'project'. User names are just email addresses. Project names are the strings "owners-", "viewers-", or "editors-" and then the project's ID. The ":W" bit at the end means "WRITE" permission. You could also use O or R or OWNER or READ or WRITE instead.

You can find out more by reading the help page: $> gsutil help acl ch